# How to use miracast on a hololens application that also uses the front camera

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a hololens application requires the use of the front facing camera, and I need to use miracast to stream the hologram feed to a PC.

Unfortunately, when miracast stops working when my application accesses the front camera of the hololens.

Is there a way for my application to use the hololens front camera, as well as for miracast to work at the same time? It is ok if the miracast only streams the holograms and not the camera feed (I cant find a setting to stream the holograms only)

Answer (score 0):

If the front camera means the photo/video camera, that this restriction does not apply to streaming MRC over Miracas after the Windows 10 October 2018 Update.

You can check the details about this limitation from link below:
[Mixed reality capture for developers - Photo/video camera access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mixed-reality-capture-for-developers#integrating-mrc-functionality-from-within-your-app)

Please ensure that your device is already update to the latest version. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/updating-hololens) about update the HoloLens.
 Please check the HoloLens is updated to the latest version.